# Access a PC remotely without user permission

Tags: windows-7, windows, remote-access, keylogger

I'm wondering if there is any way I can access a PC computer without user permission.

To be more clear :

I have a PC, on which I have Admonistrator permissions, I'm looking for a way to install something on that PC that can let me access to it anywhere and anytime without asking the user to give any password or to give permission.

INFO I know I can install a KeyLogger which can send email report, but what I'm looking for is just access the computer remotely (In ReadOnly mode, I don't want to interact whith it)

Comment: Teamviewer......."Setup unattended access" and you can jump in at any point.

Comment: Is there any tutorial about this feature !

Comment: @Sreehari below has linked a doc on how to do it.

Answer (score 1):

Teamviewer is the best option.
read this official pdf by teamviewer team for setting up unattended access via Teamviewer app.
https://www.teamviewer.com/en/res/pdf/first_steps_unattended_access_en.pdf

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your definition of "anywhere and anytime", VNC might work for you. Of course it won't do any VPNs or anything, if you really need to access it anywhere, but it would allow view only access to the machine and also interaction, if required.